# Core Data Sort Fetched Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, sorting, core-data

I need to fetch my database and order it by id. So for example, i have 2 columns in database, database_id and content. When I NSLOG last line i get all rows of "content" column. But I need to sort those "content" rows based on database_id which is 1,2,3,4,5,6 (ascending). Help ???

```
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"databaseName" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:ent];

    NSSortDescriptor *srt = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"database_id" ascending:YES];

    [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:srt]];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    if (!result)
    {
        //error
    }
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[result valueForKey:@"content"]];
```

Comment: Your code with the sort descriptor looks good to me. What exactly does not work?

Comment: Sorting is good but I'm having problem with NSString/Number. database_id goes like 1, 11, 15, 2, 3, 5....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `database_id` is stored as a string and therefore the ids are sorted as strings:

```
1, 11, 15, 2, 3, 5
```

The best solution would be to store the `database_id` as a number (e.g. "Integer 32") in the
database.

As a workaround, you can keep your strings, and use a special compare function in the 
sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor *srt = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"database_id"
                 ascending:YES
                  selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)];
```

`localizedStandardCompare` does a "Finder-like" comparison. In particular, strings containing
numbers are sorted according to their numerical value.

Comment: will then "content" (which is another database column) also be sorted depending on which id belongs to which content, or just id's will be sorted ?

Comment: @user1832330: The `result` array is sorted according to the id, therefore the content column is also sorted according to the id. So it should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks alot, will test it then see what happens.